Functoriality of adjoint action of SL_2(C) of a given representation of sl_2(C)
Given a finite-dimensional representation $\rho : \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathrm{End}(V)$, it can be lifted to a representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ via the exponential map $e^X,e^Y,e^H \in SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ which can be interpreted as
$$ e^X = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} X^k / k! $$
and moreover any element of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is a finite product of $e^A$ where $A \in \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$. More concretely, this representation, denoted as $\eta$, is $\eta(e^A) := e^{\rho(A)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \rho(A)^k / k!$.
In addition, there is the adjoint action $\mathrm{Ad}_g (X) := g A g^{-1}$ where $g \in SL_2(\mathbb{C}), A \in \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$. My question is: why does $\eta$ and adjoint action have the functoriality, i.e. $\eta(e^A e^B) = \eta(e^A) \eta(e^B)$ and $\rho(gAg^{-1}) = \eta(g) \rho(A) \eta(g^{-1})$?

For $\eta(e^A e^B) = \eta(e^A)\eta(e^B)$, this is a special case of the homomorphisms theorem, of which you can see a proof on Wikipedia. Basically this follows from the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula and the simply-connectedness of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. The second part is deducible in several ways but probably most simply from the fact that $\rho$ is the derivative of $\eta$ i.e.
$\rho(A) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\eta(e^{tA})$. Thus:
$$ \begin{align}\rho(gAg^{-1})&= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\eta(e^{tgAg^{-1}})\\
&= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\eta(ge^{tA}g^{-1})\\ &= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\eta(g)\eta(e^{tA})\eta(g^{-1})\\
&= \eta(g)\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\eta(e^{tA})\eta(g^{-1})\\
&= \eta(g)\rho(A)\eta(g^{-1}) \end{align} 
$$

I really appreciated your answer. This helps me a lot!
